# C# UWP - Update UI to display object values that have been read in by the user

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have been tasked with creating my first UWP App in C#.

The basic idea is to read in an XML file and create objects based on the data read in, then display the properties stored in the object to users in the IU.

Lets say a Person object that has a name, age, and height. I want to display the Person fields after I have read in the data but I can't get anything to show up in the UI after creating the Person object.

I have created a Person class that holds the name, age, height. I have another class that extends ObservableCollection<> and a ItemTemplate that looks for the observable class but currently nothing is showing up on the UI.

Has anyone been through a similar process or know of the correct documentation to read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in UWP you can choose between two types of binding:

1. **{x:Bind }**, is slightly faster at compile time, binds to your Framework Element code-behind class, but it is not as flexible as the other type of binding. 
   The default mode for this type of binding is OneTime, therefore you will only have your data actually propagated onto your UI, when you construct your object.
2. **{Binding }**, in this type of binding where you can only reference variables which exists inside the DataContext of a parent element. The default mode is OneWay.

With that in mind, first of all dealing with a ViewModel which is just a bunch of properties, is different from actually dealing with a Collection, since I don't think the Collection can actually detect alterations on the items itself, but rather on its structure. 
Therefore during the Add/Remove process of items in your Collection, you have to actually subscribe/unsubscribe those items to the PropertyChanged EventHandler.

Nevertheless with the following code, i think you should be able to start visualizing updates onto your UI:

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class PersonsObservable<T> : ObservableCollection<Person> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private PersonsObservable<Person> _personslist;
        public PersonsObservable<Person> personslist
        {
            get { return _personslist; }
            set
            {
                _personslist = value;
                _personslist.CollectionChanged += OnObservableCollectionChanged; 
            }
        }

        public void OnObservableCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
            if(e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        public void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, sender, sender, IndexOf((Person)sender));
            OnCollectionChanged(args);
        }

    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Person()
        {
            _name = "Walter White";
            _age = 40;
            _height = 180;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private string _name;
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int age
        {
            get
            {
                return _age;
            }
            set
            {
                _age = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _height;
        public int height
        {
            get
            {
                return _height;
            }
            set
            { 
                _height = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add Items
        PersonsList.Add(new Person());
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="DataBinding" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Age: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Height: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding height, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Add Items" Click="Button_Click" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>
```

*Test adding items *

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add Items
            PersonsList.Add(new Person());
        }
```

Expose your property and set it to the DataContext of your page (with x:Bind you wouldn't need to do this, but instead you would have to perform a cast for your code to actually compile).

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PersonsList = new PersonsObservable<Person>();
            this.DataContext = PersonsList;


            PersonsList.Add(new Person());
            PersonsList.Add(new Person());

        }

        PersonsObservable<Person> PersonsList { get; set; }
```

I haven't tested for the situation where one of the items is altered, but you can easily do that, by adding another button (and click event) and actually test if changing one of the items's properties update in your UI.

Anything else, feel free to ask, will be glad to help!

Comment: Thankyou! This is very helpfull (It does update when you change an items property).

Comment: Oh glad that is the case and that i could be helpful!
Anyway if you feel like the problem is resolved mark the answer as accepted, please.